# Putting a class function definition in another file in msvc++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm constrained by the sdk that I'm working with, it wants the plugin class to be declared and defined in the same cpp file. I would like to put the main function in a separate c++ file for aesthetic purposes though.. well not just aesthetics, its getting very tedious to scroll this much.

Since the class isn't declared in any header file, I can't just use a new source file and include the header so I'm wondering if theres any kind of preprocessor jargon for replacing a line with the contents of another cpp file as if it was part of the original cpp file all along.

Heres what I tried:

the original cpp file went like this (snippet):

```
...
void Mod1::NotifyPostCollapse(INode* /*node*/,Object* /*obj*/, IDerivedObject* /*derObj*/, int /*index*/) {}

void Mod1::ModifyObject(TimeValue t, ModContext& mc, ObjectState* os, INode* node) 
{
    lots of code here
}

void Mod1::BeginEditParams( IObjParam* ip, ULONG flags, Animatable* prev )
{
...
```

Then I tried doing this:

```
...
void Mod1::NotifyPostCollapse(INode* /*node*/,Object* /*obj*/, IDerivedObject* /*derObj*/, int /*index*/) {}

#include "ModifyObject.cpp"

void Mod1::BeginEditParams( IObjParam* ip, ULONG flags, Animatable* prev )
{
...
```

I also created the modifyobject source file and pasted the function definition there but no dice, I just get a pile of errors.

I didn't expect it to actually work but it serves well enough to illustrate what I want to do. What are my options?

EDIT: the errors I'm getting are what you'd expect from code that has no awareness of rest of the project like

```
C2065: 'TimeValue' : undeclared identifier
C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 't'
C2182: 'ModifyObject' : illegal use of type 'void'
C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

I don't know how to make the file non compilable, I tried switching the "content" flag of the file to true and/or switching the file type to plain text but either had no effect

Comment: The `#include` you used should work just fine. `#include` is pure textual "copy&paste", after all. Can you elaborate on the "pile of errors?" Ideally please provide a [reproducing example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `#include` should work fine so long as `ModifyObject.cpp` is **not** as build able source file in the vcprojx project. if it is, it will very likely fail to compile, and if it does somehow succeed, you're staring at a huge plate of duplicate link-time symbols.  You can add the .cpp file to the project, just make sure it is **not** being compiled stand-alone if you're already  `#include`-ing it somewhere. (and I personally don't recc any of this regardless).

Comment: If you want, you could always give the `#include`d source file a different extension, such as `.inl` (for "inline code").